# Tokbox - Run without CLI? Standalone example?

Tags: php, composer-php, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I've seen the sample app at tokbox API:

https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/HelloWorld/README.md 
It runs on **localhost:8080**
I wish to build a sample where :

> "Dynamically generate website URL like localhost/somekey which two
>   users can access and chat".

- Is it possible without running a CLI on my shared server?
- Can you please provide a link or sample code?
- Moreover, is there a way I can use it without composer (I'm
  integrating it in my existing system which is not composer based)?

Many thanks in advace!

Comment: Get a VPS already. You can find one for less than 3,- eur per month

Comment: How do I generate dynamic URL's for each user?